# Get particular string using preg_replace in PHP

Tags: php, drupal-7, preg-replace

I have extracted doc comment block from a file which contains values like:

```
[0] => /**
        * Shows this block on only the listed pages.
        */
[1] => /**
        * Shows this block if the associated PHP code returns TRUE.
        */
[2] => /**
        * Implements hook_help().
        */
[3] => /**
        * Implements hook_theme().
        */
```

Now I need to extract all the texts which have "**hook_***" after **Implements** .

So my final output should be an array with values like:

```
$hooks = array('hook_help', 'hook_theme');
```

What `preg_replace` expression should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the array that holds the comments is `$comments`, the following will do:

```
$hooks = array();

foreach($comments as $comment) {
    if (preg_match("/Implements (hook_\w+)\(\)/", $comment, $matches))
        $hooks[] = $matches[1];
}
```

This will match text having the word Implements followed by hook_ and at least one letter followed by (). Then will store in `$matches[1]` the first parenthesized subpattern, i.e. hooks_...

Comment: I also need some conditions that the line hook_ should come after "Implements" word and there are some chances that the line may continue after hook_ string like /** Implements hook_help and it is used to... */

Comment: I made a change for this.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. It helped me a lot :) I need some more alterations in this. The first word might be "Implements" or "Implement" or "Implementation of".  How should I write this?